# Paypal: Configuration.GetApiContext -> VS: Cannot resolve Issue

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

If I install .Net SDK and uses Sample Code, VS says: Cannot resolve symbol 'Configuration' at this line:

```
var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
```

So, what DLL or namespaces did I missed?

Answer (score 1):

It is a wrapper class around the configuration section.

Please look into \PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\Samples\Source\Utilities\Configuration.cs and create it to suit your configuration.

Don't forget to modify your web.config or app.config

```
<configSections>
     <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
</configSections>
<!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
<paypal>
<settings>
    <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
    <add name="clientId" value="youclientid" />
    <add name="clientSecret" value="yoursecret" />
</settings>
</paypal>
```